# Deserialize multiple Values C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization

This is my string that I get from my API call:

```
{"AAPL":{"price":180.38},"FB":{"price":349.37},"TSLA":{"price":1212.15}}
```

I want to Deserialize this string into a List or a Dictionary or something like that.
Here is what I thought would work:

```
public Dictionary<string, double> LoadMultiplePrice(string symbols)
    {
        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            var rawData = webClient.DownloadString($"https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/stock/market/batch?&types=price&symbols={symbols}&token={ApiKey}");
            var selectiveList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, double>>(rawData);
            return selectiveList;
        }
    }
```

or this:

```
public List<SinglePriceList> LoadMultiplePrice(string symbols)
    {
        using (var webClient = new WebClient())
        {
            var rawData = webClient.DownloadString($"https://sandbox.iexapis.com/stable/stock/market/batch?&types=price&symbols={symbols}&token={ApiKey}");
            var selectiveList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<SinglePriceList>>(rawData);
            return selectiveList;
        }
    }

public class SinglePriceList
{
    private double price { get; set; }
}
```

I get the following Errors:

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException:

...change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3])...

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException:

...Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'AAPL', line 1, position 9...

Comment: Are you sure `private double price ...` should be private?

Comment: Ahh, did not see that, but now I tried public, but still:

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException:
...change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3])...

Comment: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, SinglePriceList>>(rawData)`

Comment: Thank you that works!

Do you have any recommendation on how to make that a little smaller. Seems a but Overkill to me to make a class with just one property ("price") .
I could not find anything ‍♂️.

Comment: @Paul your object represented in the JSON string _is_ just a class with one property. So unless you can change what is sent to you, this is what you have

Comment: @maccettura Ok, if that´s the case, I can live with that. Thank you as well.

Comment: @GabrielNegut You can post that as the answer to this question if you want to. 

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var jsonParsed = JObject.Parse(rawData);

 Dictionary<string,double> stockPricesDict = jsonParsed.Properties()
.ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p=> (double)p.Value["price"] );
```

stockPrices dictionary (in json format)

```
{
  "AAPL": 180.38,
  "FB": 349.37,
  "TSLA": 1212.15
}
```

how to  use

```
var priceFB= (double) stockPricesDict["FB"];    // =349.37
```

or you can make it typed

```
List<StockPrice> stockPricesList = jsonParsed.Properties()
.Select(p => new  { Name = p.Name, Price = (double)p.Value["price"] }).ToList();
```

stockPrices list

```
[
  {
    "Name": "AAPL",
    "Price": 180.38
  },
  {
    "Name": "FB",
    "Price": 349.37
  },
  {
    "Name": "TSLA",
    "Price": 1212.15
  }
]
```

how to use

```
var priceFB=stockPricesList.FirstOrDefault(i=> i.Name=="FB").Price; // =349.37
```

class

```
public class StockPrice
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price {get; set;}
}
```